# Sum '$push' array within MongoDB aggregation

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Is it possible to sum an array returned from a `$push` operator within the `$group` stage?

```
{
  $group: {
    _id: '$randomId',
    fruitKind: '$fruitId',
    ...,
    ripeness: { $push: {$cond: [ { $eq: [ "$fruitComplexion", "ripe" ] }, 1, 0 ] }}
   }
},
{  
  $project : {
    _id: 1,
   totalRipeFruit : "$ripeness",
  }
}
```

Right now this simply returns each value in the array:
For example,

```
totalRipeFruit: Array[5] -> [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

However, I am aiming towards simplifying this to return the sum of the array such as (using the previous example):

```
totalRipeFruit: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I figured it out by using the `$sum` and `$add` operator instead:

```
ripeness: { $sum: { $add: {$cond: [ { $eq: [ "$fruitComplexion", "ripe" ] }, 1, 0 ] } } }
```

Comment: It should work fine without the $add and should be fine only with the $sum

Comment: @anish True. Thanks for the feedback.